# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__config_fbConfig__.a.database is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

What im doing wrong here and why im getting this error, retrieving extra info that i saved with createUserWithEmailAndPassword

SignUP form details

````
  const {email, password } = this.state;
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((data) => {
      const { user } = data;
      if(user){
        firebase.database().ref('Users/Trainers/' + user.uid).set({
          email: this.state.email,
          firstName: this.state.firstName,
          lastName: this.state.lastName,
          role: this.state.role,
          datecreated: Date.now()
    });  
    this.props.history.push('/trainerSignin');
      }
  }).catch((error) => {
    this.setState({ error: error });
  });```
````

Profile Page Details

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user){
      const db = firebase.database().ref('Users/Trainers/' + user.uid).once('value', snap => {
        console.log(user.email);
        console.log(user.firstName);
      })
    }
  })
```

Here is my DB
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [firebase.database.ref is not a function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598993/firebase-database-ref-is-not-a-function-error)

Comment: No, it is not..